# better and best as forms of adjective and adverb

Tags: etymology

Why do both 'good' and 'well' have the same suppletive comparative and superlative forms in English? What were the steps in that historic process? Were these two words borrowed with these forms or is it something that occurred in OE? Unfortunately I can't find a clear answer to this question. It is not clear either when exactly 'good' began to be used as an adverb and 'well' as an adjective.

Comment: It may have happened before Old English. German: *gut, besser, besten*.

Comment: These, of course, were not borrowed, as is well documented on the Wikipedia page on [suppletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion), and in [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/?term=well). The rest is an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Wiktionary says that *gōd*, *betera* and *betst* were adjectives in Old English, and doesn't mention the comparative and superlative forms of *wel*; I would guess this means they were regular (although Wiktionary isn't the most trustworthy reference). So at some point, *better* and *best* became adverbs as well as adjectives.

Comment: Presumably we shouldn't simply reproduce OED here? They say it's Germanic (before OE), but can't identify the real root of *better* in Germanic.

Comment: There are hundreds of known Proto-Germanic roots that show up regularly in Germanic languages that don't trace back to Proto-Indo-European. Those Germani got around quite a lot, after all, before they settled in northern Europe. That and Grimm's Law conspire to make Germanic languages noticeably different from Romance and Greek.

Comment: Have you tried asking on linguisticsSE? Perhaps, languages other than English have something to do with the question as well.

Comment: @Kris 37 Thank you. Sounds like a good idea. I will. Although the tips I've already got helped me to direct my search and something interesting has transpired about the Proto-Germanic adjective *bataz* (please see my comment below)

Answer (score 4):

*Better* and *best* (and *worse* and *worst*) are suppletive in many languages: Latin *bonus* ("good"), *melior* ("better"), *optimus* ("best"); Russian *добрый* (dobry, "good") *лучше* (lučše, "better"); Welsh *da* ("good), *gwell* ("better").

As for *better* and *best* serving for both adjective and adverb: I suspect it is *well* which is suppletive, replacing any derivative of *good*.

Comment: @Peter Shor It does seem quite complicated. What a closer look at the Proto-Germanic forms in Wiktionary indicates is that there used to be the adjective _bataz_ (from bhAd) as well as _godaz_ and both meant "good" and had the same comparative and superlative forms *batizo* and *batistaz*. The comparative and superlative forms of the adverb *wela* were *batiz* and *batist* - all of these clearly related to *bataz*, which itself has not survived. So at some point the base form of the adjective and the degree forms of the adverb were NOT suppletive. It's not clear why *bataz* and *wela* were.

Comment: @RegDwighт Thank you for your correction. By "borrowed" I of course meant that they are of Proto-Germanic origin.